# libgit2 - write tree object to mysql odb backend

Tags: mysql, libgit2

I followed [libgit2-backend](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2-backends) project to create mysql backend for libgit2 ODB backend.

It's fairly easy to create blob objects and put it in mysql-backed ODB, I'm using git_blob_create_frombuffer

But when it comes to other ODB objects like tree, it's difficult.

As far as I know from libgit2 document 101 samples and API reference, you can write tree using treebuilder or index, but both appoach require path.
As the repository is a fake one created using git_repository_wrap_odb

I've tried using relative path like 'README.md' to build tree or index, then use git_treebuilder_write or git_index_write_tree_to, but both failed at path validation.

I would like to know my options to write tree object to mysql odb backend.

Thanks in advance!

sample code:

```
git_odb_backend_mysql(odb_backend,"localhost", "git2", "git2", "git2", 0, NULL, 0);

git_odb_new(&odb_backend->odb);
git_repository_wrap_odb(&repo, odb_backend->odb);
git_odb_add_backend(odb_backend->odb, odb_backend, 1);

git_blob_create_frombuffer(&oid, repo, str, strlen(str));

git_treebuilder_new(&bld, repo, NULL);
git_treebuilder_insert(NULL, bld, "README.md", &oid, 0100644);   
git_treebuilder_write(&treeoid, repo, bld);
```

This was tested on windows 7 32-bit, visual studio 2013 express for desktop edition

Libgit2 version: 0.22.1

I put my testing code into libgit2_clar

the str was written to mysql:

```
select  lower(hex(oid)),type, size, convert(uncompress(data) using utf8)
from git2_odb;

oid                                       type size data
5dd01c177f5d7d1be5346a5bc18a569a7410c2ef  3    13   Hello, world!
```

Error accured while calling git_treebuilder_insert

Error Message:
Unhandled exception at 0x013A56A1 in libgit2_clar.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Visual studio debug stopped at libgit2/src/win32/path_w32.c, line#196

```
  if (path__is_absolute(src)) {
```

Comment: What error are you getting? '/README.md' which you mention fails is not a relative path

Comment: Hi, Carlos, thanks for the response, sorry I meant "README.md" as relative path. I added more details like testing environment and error message. The error happens when executing git_treebuilder_insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're getting a segfault/AV, it's a bug somewhere inside libgit2. The most likely place this comes from is the path validation to make sure no dangerous or invalid paths are being inserted. The likely place for this `NULL` value to come from is the repository's path, as it's used as a way to figure out if the final path would try to write into the gitdir of whatever checks it out.

The constructor you're using was only ever meant for reading out of a dabatase and AFAIK has never been tested as a way to write. I would suggest using opening a repository and then setting the odb with `git_repository_set_odb()` if you do want to use the repository interface for something.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Carlos! I'll try and let you know

Comment: Hi, Carlos, by opening a dummy repo on disk and set_odb, I'm able to write tree object into mysql table!

Thanks a lot!